# Gravitational waves, gauge transformations and observables

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, gauge-invariance

In GR the (perturbed) metric obeys a wave equation in a certian gauge. The same thing happens EM waves, $\Box^2A_{\mu}=0$ only on a certian gauge, but $\Box^2F_{\mu\nu}=0$ without fixing the gauge.

I believe the reason this is not a "problem" is due to the potential not being observable, while the field are.

In the analogy between GR and EM, $g_{\mu\nu}$ corresponds to $A_{\mu}$ and $F_{\mu\nu}$ to $R_{\mu\nu\sigma\lambda}$ (not sure on this one).

Now, gauge transformations in GR correspond to coordinate transformations which means that fixing the gauge corresponds to fixing a certian kind of reference frames (not sure on this one either).

However from what i read the metric is actually observable and realatable to the change in length, and in a special case reduces to

$$\delta x=\frac{1}{2}h_{+}x$$, where $h_{+}$ is the + polarization component of the wave and is part of the metric.

My question is, how can the metric be observable, but the wave equation realized in a certain gauge? Which are the mistakes in my reasoning?

Comment: A better analogy would be the connection, not the metric tensor, playing the role of the gauge field. Gauge theories of gravity uses exactly this type of construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metric is not diffeomorphism invariant, it changes under an infinitesimal diffeomorphism, $X$, by the Lie derivative of the metric along $X$.  Diffeomorphisms which act trivially at the boundary of spacetime are gauge transformations.  The metric transforms under the action of these diffeomorphisms, so it is not gauge invariant.

Now for definiteness, let's say we are in asymptotically flat spacetime, near null infinity (i.e., far from matter sources).  Then there is a standard way of expanding the metric in Bondi coordinates.  Let $r$ be the Bondi radial coordinate.  At low orders in the $1/r$ expansion near null infinity, the metric itself can be directly measured using the memory effect.  That's because diffeomorphisms which change the metric at sufficiently low orders in the $1/r$ expansion are not gauge transformations, they are physical transformations called BMS transformations.

When people solve the wave equation perturbatively, they are expanding the metric with respect to some coordinate system that is suited to their problem.  Which diffeomorphisms are physical and which are gauge transformations will depend on the details of the problem.  I outlined how things work near null infinity for asymptotically flat spacetimes.

Almost every problem has a gauge-invariant notion of energy.  So no matter what coordinates you use, you can probably extract the energy carried by the gravitational waves in a gauge invariant way.